# ng2 pdf-viewer: Some text opacity decreases when zooming in

Tags: css, angular2-template, bootstrap-4

implemented custom zoom in and zoom out functionality. On clicking zoom in i increase `[zoom]` value to 0.25. On clicking zoom out i decrease `[zoom]` value to 0.25.

pdf container div has width of `col-md-6` and max-height is set to `950px`.
`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are set to `scroll`.

On clicking zoom in when horizontal scroll bar appears then text after scrollbar shaded up.

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by using background-color in rgba

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,255);
```